# Array Index Error

Tags: c++, arrays

```
int a[10];
std::cin >> a[12];
std::cout << a[12];
```

Shouldn't the `a[12]` line raise an error as the array is only declared for 10 indexes? Is there something obvious I'm missing, or has it always been like this?

Comment: It's been like this since the earliest days of C.

Answer (score 3):

You are free to index out of range, but it is [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239938/c-accesses-an-array-out-of-bounds-gives-no-error-why). This could eventually manifest in memory stomping, a write access error, or other.

Comment: So is there a way to restrict input if index is more that that declared, without manually checking if the index location is more than the max defined index?

Comment: @MayurMohan, Use `std::array` and its `at` member function, or check the index against the size if you actually plan on it going over sometime.